# Filter emails which are older than X days only with several "or" statements

Tags: filter, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-webextensions

I will explain what I want to do and also why, just because someone knows a better way of what to do to reach the why.

My goal is to have an Inbox where most Emails stay for 14 days and only after that are being sorted into their respective folders (some known unimportant ones like newsletters get sorted right away). The reason for that is that the email client we use on our phones (Spark) does not seem to alert or easily show if new emails arrived in a subfolder so we tend to not see them until I check on the PC with Thunderbird.

I am already using the FiltaQuilla plugin to use regex matches on specific headers (most of the time I match on sender, recipients and x-original-to but sometimes other headers come into play).
In one filter rule I would have several "or" matches to these headers (e.g. if either From/To/CC/Bcc matches that regex then move it to a specific folder).

This works but I cannot put a nested and rule to only move it if the message is older than 14 days.

I tried to create a rule that applies always (all checkboxed marked) and matches on any email less than 14 days old, the action is to "Stop filter execution". I put all filters I want to apply only after 14 days behind this rule.
I was expecting this to stop any filter evaluation past this rule if the email is not 14 days or older, however this seems to do nothing as the filters after it still get applied automatically.

So the question is how can I create a filter that matches on several headers using regex which only applies if the message is older than 14 days?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: like screenshots? or should I attach the file that includes all filters?

Answer (score 0):

The exact thing you want is not possible with filters.
I found a decent surrogate doing this:

1. Created a new Parking folder
2. Configure Parking for X days of retention

The result is practically what you want